# Canvas and drawing.

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to add to a canvas different controls and collections. It seems hard to bind them via XAML. I can bind only one collection.. Also i would like to add background image built from tiles -user. So is it better to handle it via code or via XAML ?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question... could you provide more details please?

Comment: Me too. I can't understand the question at all. Parhs, could you please rephrase/edit your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to add to a canvas different controls and collections. It
>   seems hard to bind them via XAML.

For this set your canvas as the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` and binding `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to the list of items that you want your canvas to display.

see this example... http://forums.silverlight.net/p/29753/96439.aspx

> I can bind only one collection...

You can bind to mutliple collections through what we call `CompositeCollection`. see the example in the bottom of the page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx

> Also i would like to add background image built from tiles -user. So
>   is it better to handle it via code or via XAML ?

[How to set a .PNG image as a TILED background image for my WPF Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725184/how-to-set-a-png-image-as-a-tiled-background-image-for-my-wpf-form)