# How to achieve hatch pattern?

Tags: wpf, xaml, hatchstyle

I want to display hatch pattern like in the below image in wpf.Is it possible to achieve this in wpf?[image]

Comment: You can use Visual Brush in Tile mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725184/how-to-set-a-png-image-as-a-tiled-background-image-for-my-wpf-form

Comment: Don't use a VisualBrush. A DrawingBrush is much simpler.